# Looking for Specman methods to get first/next/last enumerated value

Tags: specman, e

Are there built-in methods in Specman that give me the value of the first, last, and next value of an enumerated variable? 
For example:

```
type color_e: [blue, green, red, yellow, orange];`
        var color: color_e;

color = <want to assign first value of color_e>;  //blue
       …
        color = <next value>;     //which is green
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use the all_values() method, which returns a list of all value of the enumerated type. You can then play with the list as you want.

example:

```
 type color : [RED, BLUE, GREEN];
    extend color : [BLACK, CYAN];

    extend sys {
       run() is also {
         var x : color;
         foreach in all_values(color) {
            x = it;
            print x;
         };
     };
    };


Running the test ...
  x = RED
  x = BLUE
  x = GREEN
  x = BLACK
  x = CYAN
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the following reflection solution, but woner if there is an easier way.

```
<'

 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 -- Define an enumerated type and populate
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  type color_e : [blue, green, red, yellow, orange];


  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Extend sys
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  extend sys {

  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Use the reflection facility to get the number of labels in an
  -- enumerated type
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  get_num_labels(enum_item: string) : int is {

    var size : int; -- number of labels defined in the enumerated type

    -- Find the type if defined
    for each (t) in rf_manager.get_user_types() { 
       if t is a rf_enum and t.get_name() == enum_item {
          -- return the size of the list
         result = t.as_a(rf_enum).get_items().size();
       }; // if t is a rf_en...
    }; // for each (t) in...
 }; // get_num_labels( ...

 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 -- Use the reflection facility to return the value of the
 -- label defined in an enumerated type at a particular index
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   get_enum_label_value(enum_item: string, idx: int) : int is {

    var size : int; -- number of labels defined in the enumerated type

    -- Find the type if defined
    for each (t) in rf_manager.get_user_types() { 
       if t is a rf_enum and t.get_name() == enum_item {

          -- get the size of the list
          size = get_num_labels(enum_item);

          -- return the value of the item in the list at the specified index if legal
          if (idx < size) {
            result = t.as_a(rf_enum).get_items()[idx].get_value();
          } else {
            dut_errorf("Index requested is greater than the number of labels in the enumerated type %s\n",enum_item);
          };

       }; // if t is a rf_en...
    }; // for each (t) in...
 }; // get_enum_label_value( ...


 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 -- Extend the run phase
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   run() is also {

     var color : color_e;
     var size  : int;

     size = get_num_labels("color_e");
     messagef (NONE, "Enumerated type color_e has %d labels, and they are...\n", size);

     for i from 0 to (size-1) {
        color = get_enum_label_value("color_e",i).as_a(color_e);
        messagef (NONE, "%s\n", color);
     }; -- for

   }; // run is also

 }; // extend sys

'>
```

Comment: To get a specific type in reflection by name, there is no need to loop over get_user_types(). There is an existing reflection method for that: rf_manager.get_type_by_name(). So, you could simply do:  

if rf_manager.get_type_by_name(the_name) is a rf_enum (rfe) then {
     result = rfe.get_items().size()
};

or something like that.

Also, even when we do need to loop over all enumerated types, we can do it like this:

for each rf_enum in rf_manager.get_user_types() { ... }

so there is no need to explicitly check whether each one "is a rf_enum", and no need in the explicit as_a(ef_enum).

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution (in addition to `all_values()`) is with reflection. Given a `rf_enum`, we can call its `get_items()` method to get a list of all enum items.

However, there are some differences between the refleciton soluition and `all_values()`, which are important to know.
One difference is that if some enum items are given explicit numeric values, not necessarily in increasing order, then `all_values()` will return the values in increasing order, but `rf_enum.get_items()` will return the items in the order of declaration.
For example, if we have:

```
type foo: [A=5, B, C=1, D];
```

then `all_values(foo)` will return C, D, A, B (in this order - according to the respective numeric values 1, 2, 5, 6), but `rf_manager.get_type_by_name("foo").as_a(rf_enum).get_items()` will return A, B, C, D.
If you want to get the reflection result sorted by the numeric values, you can do, for example, `rf_manager.get_type_by_name("foo").as_a(rf_enum).get_items().sort(it.get_value())`.

Another difference is that when we have several enumerated types based on each other, with different generative sub-ranges, then `all_values()` for a specific type will return only values that belong to that types's generative range, but `rf_enum.get_items()` will return all items.
For example:

```
type t1: [A, B, C, D];
type t2: t1[A..B];
type t3: t2;
extend t2: [E];
```

With this example, `rf_enum.get_items()` will return A, B, C, D, E for any of t1, t2, or t3. But `all_values()` will give different results, according to the generative range of each type. `all_values(t1)` will return A, B, C, D; `all_values(t2)` will return A, B, E; and `all_values(t3)` will return A, B.